# compare two array and put a status in an other array if it exist or not

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

so i have an array with all the players and one with only the one that are selected and i want to have an other array with the status if he is selected or not. i tried comparing and pushing the element with the status but didnt achieve what i wanted.

here are the arrays

```
  const all = [
    {
      playerId: '294',
      firstName: 'MMM',
    },
    {
      playerId: '295',
      firstName: 'arkiv',
    },
    {
      playerId: '296',
      firstName: 'julio',
    },
    {
      playerId: '297',
      firstName: 'sss',
    },
  ];

const selected = [
    {
      playerId: '296',
      firstName: 'julio',
    },
    {
      playerId: '297',
      firstName: 'sss',
    },
  ];
```

and this is what i want to achive

```
  const res = [
    { playerId: '294', firstName: 'MMM', status: false },
    { playerId: '295', firstName: 'arkiv', status: false },
    { playerId: '296', firstName: 'julio', status: true },
    { playerId: '297', firstName: 'sss', status: true },
  ];
```

i set up an environment to work here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-lkcqcd?file=src%2FApp.js

thanks for attention!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to check if the id of the player is in the selected array.

```js
const all=[{playerId:'294',firstName:'MMM',},{playerId:'295',firstName:'arkiv',},{playerId:'296',firstName:'julio',},{playerId:'297',firstName:'sss',},],selected=[{playerId:'296',firstName:'julio',},{playerId:'297',firstName:'sss',},];
all.forEach(player => player.status = 
              selected.some(x => x.playerId === player.playerId));
console.log(all);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) of selected players and using this set you can add the `status` field.

```js
const 
  all = [{ playerId: "294", firstName: "MMM" }, { playerId: "295", firstName: "arkiv" }, { playerId: "296", firstName: "julio" }, { playerId: "297", firstName: "sss" }],
  selected = [{ playerId: "296", firstName: "julio" }, { playerId: "297", firstName: "sss" }],
  selectedSet = new Set(selected.map((player) => player.playerId)),
  res = all.map((player) => ({ ...player, status: selectedSet.has(player.playerId) }));

console.log(res);
```

You can also use [Array.prototype.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) instead of creating a set but this wouldn't be optimal unless the size of the `selected` array is quite small.

```js
const 
  all = [{ playerId: "294", firstName: "MMM" }, { playerId: "295", firstName: "arkiv" }, { playerId: "296", firstName: "julio" }, { playerId: "297", firstName: "sss" }],
  selected = [{ playerId: "296", firstName: "julio" }, { playerId: "297", firstName: "sss" }],
  res = all.map((player) => ({
    ...player,
    status: !!selected.find((selPlayer) => selPlayer.playerId === player.playerId),
  }));

console.log(res);
```

Comment: thanks for your time. i just started and and dont know that you can even do somethings lol. if you have some recommendation for me i would appreciate it. also do you think the new Set is more optimal than the answer above with forEach

Comment: You can go through the [MDN JS Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide). And yes, set is more optimal than finding in an array.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array#map` and `Array#includes` as in the following demo:

```js
const all = [ { playerId: '294', firstName: 'MMM', }, { playerId: '295', firstName: 'arkiv', }, { playerId: '296', firstName: 'julio', }, { playerId: '297', firstName: 'sss', }, ],

      selected = [ { playerId: '296', firstName: 'julio', }, { playerId: '297', firstName: 'sss', }, ],

      output = all.map(
          player => 
          ({
              ...player,
              status:selected.map(({playerId}) => playerId)
              .includes(player.playerId)
          })
      );

console.log( output );
```